# updateViewConstraints() called twice after screen rotation

Tags: ios, custom-keyboard

I'm implementing custom ios keyboard. I have an issue with updates of keyboard views when rotating screen. The problem is that animation of update is not smooth (view sizes and positions change few times). I think this happens because `updateViewConstraints()` method called twice after rotation. In my override method of `updateViewConstraints()` I remove and add keyboard height constraint.

```
let portraitHeight:CGFloat = UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad ? 315 : 264
let landscapeHeight:CGFloat = UIDevice.currentDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .Pad ? 420 : 200
var heightConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
override func updateViewConstraints() {
    super.updateViewConstraints()

    if (self.view.frame.size.width == 0 || self.view.frame.size.height == 0) {
        return
    }

    let isLandscape =  !(self.view!.frame.size.width == self.screenWidth * ((self.screenWidth < self.screenHeight) ? 1 : 0) + self.screenHeight * ((self.screenWidth > self.screenHeight) ? 1 : 0))

    self.inputView!.removeConstraint(self.heightConstraint)
    if (isLandscape) {
        self.heightConstraint.constant = self.landscapeHeight;
        self.inputView!.addConstraint(self.heightConstraint)
    } else {
        self.heightConstraint.constant = self.portraitHeight;
        self.inputView!.addConstraint(self.heightConstraint)
    }
}
```

Is this okay that `updateViewConstraints()` called twice when rotating screen? And how to achieve smooth animation on screen rotation?

Thanks for any advance!